# Rename all columns from all tables with specific column name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Is there a way I can rename all column names that are called 'location' to 'location_name' within all schemas in my PostgreSQL database?

I am fairly new to SQL and am aware there is an ALTER TABLE command but don't know if it is possible to somehow loop through all tables?

Comment: Always have a script to re-create a database from scratch. Edit that script.

Comment: Better fit [dba.se]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have superuser privileges you can make the changes in one sweep in the system catalogs:

```
UPDATE pg_attribute
SET attname = 'location_name'
WHERE attname = 'location';
```

Comment: Wow, this is a terrible idea. You should not be modifying the catalog directly.

Answer (score 8):

You need dynamic SQL for this using an anonymous PL/pgSQL block to do this in an automated way:

```
do
$$
declare
  l_rec record;
begin
  for l_rec in (select table_schema, table_name, column_name 
                from information_schema.columns 
                where table_schema = 'public' 
                  and column_name = 'location') loop
     execute format ('alter table %I.%I rename column %I to %I_name', l_rec.table_schema, l_rec.table_name, l_rec.column_name, l_rec.column_name);
  end loop;
end;
$$
```

If you have multiple schemas or your tables are not in the `public` schema, replace the condition `where table_schema = 'public'` with the appropriate restriction.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I was successful with Patrick's reply but I am sure this would work as well.

Comment: @Chris: messing around with the system catalogs is really not a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think the closest you will get is running something like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(
  'ALTER TABLE %I.%I.%I RENAME COLUMN %I TO %I;',
  catalog_name,
  schema_name,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  'location_name'
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name = 'location';
```

If you run that in psql, you can follow it with `\gexec` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all `location` columns in your database with

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE column_name = 'location';
```

And probably use some programming language to then execute all rename queries. There are `information_schema` tables in almost every database management system (although, they are sometimes called/structured differently).